# Couchbase Lite and XCode 7 (Swift)

Tags: ios, xcode, couchbase-lite

Am trying to use Couchbase Lite, I do everything from here http://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/mobile/1.1.0/develop/training/build-first-ios-app/create-new-project/index.html
but I get error:

```
ld: building for iOS simulator, but linking against dylib built for OSX, file '/Documents/xcode/Couchbase Lite/Couchbase Lite/CouchbaseLite.framework/CouchbaseLite' for architecture x86_64
```

Thanks

Comment: Make sure you're downloading the Couchbase Mobile SDK, and not the Couchbase Server SDK from the downloads page.

Comment: I suggest you to use library via Cocoapods instead of manually installation.You can check [Couchbase](https://github.com/couchbase/couchbase-lite-ios) at github.

Comment: check cblite data using this approach : https://stackoverflow.com/a/52491560/3400991

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears like you've integrated Couchbase Lite framework for OS X. You can't use OS X binaries in iOS Simulator apps; they aren't compatible.

Download [iOS framework](http://www.couchbase.com/dl/releases/couchbase-lite/ios/1.1.1/couchbase-lite-ios-enterprise_1.1.1-18.zip) by clicking [here](http://www.couchbase.com/nosql-databases/downloads#ProductCouchbase_Lite). That should solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks! The problem was in community edition, but when i try enterprise everything work perfect ?!

Comment: @miff I bet you downloaded the wrong link.  When you go to the downloads page you need to choose iOS, not OS X.

Comment: @borrrden probably :) But am give up to Couchbase for now (current project), Realm is much better