# How to find Couchbase Mobile DB file in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, couchbase-lite

I want to find Couchbase Mobile DB file location in iOS and please also describe how to open db file?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

If you are using CBM 1.4 or earlier,  you can locate the location of the cblite2 db file as discussed here

https://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/mobile/1.4/guides/couchbase-lite/native-api/manager/index.html#dude-wheres-my-database-file

To view the database , you can use CouchbaseLiteViewer which is  (not officially supported ) Mac application
https://github.com/couchbaselabs/CouchbaseLiteViewer.

You could also use any sqlite browser such as http://sqlitebrowser.org to browse the sqlite content

Comment: This is deprecated now.

Comment: @ShobhakarTiwari What do you mean by "deprecated" ? The solution indicated above applies to CBM 1.4 and earlier as indicated .

Answer (score 1):

> CouchbaseLiteViewer is not updated for checking data in Cblite 2.0 , i
>   waiting for it so as of now following way check Cblite db data and it
>   will work.

**Latest solution Couchbase 2.0 db check:**

There is a command line tool which I believe is inside the zip file that you download to get Couchbase Lite (look in tools) called "cblite" which is similar to the sqlite command line tool. It can perform operations on a database such as listing documents, querying, etc.

1. Download Couchbase sdk from the website
2. It comes with the folder inside this, there is a folder called Tools .
   [image]

Screenshots for reference :

3.Inside tools cblite is there , just launch it . now suppose i have cblite db .

Use following way to query and this tools provide you comannd terminal way to search data/document :

**I tried this and it works**

shobhakar$ ./cblite /Downloads/mobile-travel-sample-master/ios/TravelSample/TravelSample/prebuilt/travel-sample.cblite2
Opened database /Downloads/mobile-travel-sample-master/ios/TravelSample/TravelSample/prebuilt/travel-sample.cblite2/

This is the current solution and this is awesome.

Reference link : https://github.com/couchbase/couchbase-lite-ios/issues/2176#issuecomment-423921463